# Is device is having passkey configuration for input keyhandle?

Tags: android, ios, webauthn, passkey

I have list of passkey keyhandle(id) in database which can be retrieved in mobile app client by rest API. I wanna differentiate and show current device passkey (which is configured from that mobile device itself) from the list of various device's passkey configurations.

Is there any API available to find is device having passkey configuration for this particular  keyhandle or not?(In android & IOS)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any API available to find is device having passkey configuration for this particular keyhandle or not?(In android & IOS)

There is no API that will silently return whether the device contains a given credential. However, with passkeys you mightn't need to know which credential is on the current device, rather an app can ask for *a* passkey assertion and the device will show an account picker listing the applicable ones. On iOS (and in the forthcoming Android 14) it's possible to ask that the account picker only show if there